# How to block or whitelist specific webpages or files within a domain but block most of the domain?

Tags: dns, firewall, hosts

I know how to use /etc/hosts to redirect [www.herpaderp.com](http://www.herpaderp.com) to 0.0.0.0
The problem is I need one page file from the website on a regular basis.

I want to whitelist [www.herpaderp.com/dir/foo.bar](http://www.herpaderp.com/dir/foo.bar) while continuing to block the remainder of the domain.
Alternately, though less ideal, allowing the whole domain but manually blocking some branches of its directory tree, maybe with some wildcard or regex pattern.